# Website with Django 3 and django_plotly_dash does not update website

Tags: django, plotly-dash

I have a website that contains a dashboard that is based on plotly-dash. I want to change it and I can see the changes when running `./manage.py runserver`, but not when serving is with nginx. I did

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

Also deleted all `.pyc` files and `__pycache__` and restarted supervisor and nginx with :

```
sudo supervisorctl stop all && sudo supervisorctl reread && sudo supervisorctl update && sudo supervisorctl start all && sudo service nginx restart
```

Which runs through. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I had to kill some processes myself using `sudo killall python`. It seems sometimes supervisor forgets to kill some processes.